# I can't use the shutdown command because the system "Failes to Connect to bus: No such file or directory"

Tags: 16.04, server, shutdown

If I use the `shutdown` command my system throws an error. It happens even if I use `shutdown -h` or `shutdown -h now`

```
user@Domain:~$ sudo shutdown
[sudo] password for user:
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
user@Domain:~$ shutdown -h
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
user@Domain:~$ shutdown -h now
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

The only command that I can get to work is `sudo shutdown -h now`

Is this expected behavior?

dbus is installed and up to date...

```
user@Domain:~$ sudo apt-get install dbus
[sudo] password for user:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
dbus is already the newest version (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was with `dbus` - even though it was installed and up-to-date, it was still broken.

You can reinstall it with

`apt-get install --reinstall dbus`

Comment: Ah, didn't see the comments on the question. Maybe you want to rephrase your answer, so it does not start with a question and states something like "...finally it turned out that reinstalling..."

Answer (score 1):

Install `dbus` module on your machine
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus

Comment: It's already installed. Just updated the OP to reflect this.